# Unable to direct connect NICE DCV through browser with a password containing & (ampersand)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to provide the users an easy way to connect to instances using NICE DCV through the browser.

All good, I redirect them to https://example.com:8443/?username=xxx&password=yyy and it works as expected.
However, when a password contains & (ampersand), I encode it normally with %26, and it doesn't work.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I though this should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Reported it to AWS as a bug and they aknowledged that it is a bug.

I tried to see if we could use the Nice DCV Web SDK, but it seems to only support REACT. If you are using REACT this might be an option for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).